# Scala check if a ListBuffer[MyType] contains one element

Tags: scala, listbuffer

I have two class:

```
class Item(val description: String, val id: String) 

class ItemList {
  private var items : ListBuffer[Item] = ListBuffer()
}
```

How can I check if items contain one item with description=x and id=y?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be

```
list.exists(item => item.description == x && item.id == y)
```

If you also implement `equals` for your class (or even better, make it a `case class` which does that automatically), you can simplify that to

```
case class Item(description: String, id: String)
 // automatically everything a val, 
 // you get equals(), hashCode(), toString(), copy() for free
 // you don't need to say "new" to make instances

list.contains(Item(x,y))
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
def containsIdAndDescription(id: String, description: String) = {
   items.exists(item => item.id == id && item.description == description )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe think of these approaches, also:

```
//filter will return all elements which obey to filter condition

list.filter(item => item.description == x && item.id == y)

//find will return the fist element in the list

list.find(item => item.description == x && item.id == y)
```